# How to expand Electromagnetic fields in term of Laguerre–Gaussian (LG) beams?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, second-quantization, canonical-conjugation

I was studying canonical quantization for the electromagnetic fields. I know that we can expand our fields in other normal modes which one of them is the Laguerre–Gaussian (LG)  wave set but in most books the procedure is not written.

I wanted to ask that if there is some good reference for this?

edit :
i wanted this refrences because i wanted to see why the orbital angular momentum of these beams have well defined values and their eigenstates which probably are these normal egein modes (LG beams)

Comment: You should consider adding more background and spelling out acronyms (what LG means) so it can be more useful to the broader community. Considering that most books according to you don't expand on it I would imagine few would know what you're asking.

Comment: sure. thank you for your tip

Comment: No problem, the more clear and self contained the question typically the better it is received. I'm not familiar with it myself but I hope someone can come along and offer more constructive information.